# How to know when an user rates an iOS app/game

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am developing a game for iOS. I would like to implement a feature that allow the user rate my app and, if he does it, he will get points for my game. 
I know how to display an screen, menu, whatever to ask the user rate my app, but I don't know how to know when the user does it, I mean, the user completes all the process and I get my valuation.

Comment: Maybe you can just have a "RATE THE APP" button, send the user on her way to the program store, give her credit and just have faith in that she actually *did* rate you. I think most people would do the rating when they are there, especially since they don't know that they got the points before going back to your program anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only thing you can do is to use something like [Appirater](https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater)

You could recommend to your clients to review and rate your app. But I think that you don't be able of know if they finally rate or not.

Comment: Definitely. I'm using it and it's awesome. +1

Answer (score 9):

You will unfortunately not know this since apple won't give you the feedback on it. The best you can do is give them the "rate my app link" and attribute them with the points if they click on it. I've seen games that provided points to the user for rating and they give the points when the user clicks on the link.

Answer (score 2):

As a few people have mentioned not really possible to know if people who go to the store actually rate the App. But AskingPoint has an interesting solution that allows you to use your App Analytics (full disclosure Im a founder) to present your best users with a rating widget. We think this will increase the odds they actually DO rate it. And you will have the count of the number of people that were taken to rate on a given day, and could correlate that with number of ratings you got. It helps, but is not exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to know if a user actually rates the app. You can provide them with a callout to take them to the app store (with the intention of getting them to rate it). However you can't actually see if they rated it, only if they tapped the link in the first place.